# Error in Listview android:layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Recently i started learning about Android App development. Today I am trying to build a ListView. But In Listview properties I have got a error in android:layout_height. I set My layout_height to "match_parent", "wrap_content" and "fill_parent". But in every case a got red line under the this.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sourav.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting the relative layouts width and height to fill parent. It's working as is for me without trying anything though.

Comment: XML editor in Android Studio isn't accurate, try to compile your app. If it compiles successfully, so your codes are okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto File -> 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' and restart studio.

Comment: Don't need to bold the entire answer just to attract attention. It implies shouting. Use bold only when you want to highlight something.

Comment: @AnoopKanyan Why should this fix the problem?

Comment: It still shows red underline in xml, but run in mobile fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change your list view to the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wrote a short blog post after fighting this myself at:  http://jamesbyars.github.io/android/Android-ListView-Height/

Comment: Regardless of whether this answer is right or wrong, One thing is correct. Why not use a LinearLayout when you have just a ListView to put there. There is really no sense in putting the RelativeLayout there.

Comment: Red Line Under "0dp"

Answer (score 1):

1.Just go to Build-->Rebuild project 
2. Build --> clean project
 hope it will work :)